# Script executed in EC2 User Data with nohup doesn't run until manually SSHing in

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, user-data

I have the following command in my EC2 User Data:

```
setsid nohup /root/go/src/prometheus-to-cloudwatch-master/dist/bin/prometheus-to-cloudwatch --cloudwatch_namespace TestBox/Prometheus --cloudwatch_region eu-west-1 --cloudwatch_publish_timeout 5 --prometheus_scrape_interval 30 --prometheus_scrape_url MyScrapeUrl &
```

This script will take metrics published at the `prometheus_scrape_url` and push them to CloudWatch. By default this script runs in the foreground and every 30 seconds will output the number of metrics pushed to CloudWatch. I have added `setsid nohup` to run the script in the background in a new session.

The issue here is that the script doesn't seem to run until I SSH into the box following initialisation and `su` to the root user (it's like it's queued to be run when I next SSH as the root user).

My expected behaviour is that the script runs as part of the user data and I should never need to SSH into the box.

The script in question is: https://github.com/cloudposse/prometheus-to-cloudwatch

Comment: I am not sure I understood your requirements correctly. (I am not familiar with EC2 user data.) But from what I could guess, you want to run something periodically. Did you consider running it as `cron` job? (You would find many examples via google on how to use `cron`.)

Comment: @anishsane Thanks for your response, no I'm not looking to run something periodicially, I'm looking to run a script on first boot of my AWS EC2 instance and I'm seeing strange behaviour.

Comment: 'first boot of my AWS EC2' like /etc/init.d or /etc/rc.local etc?